# Git subtree merge on master

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-subtree

I have two repo branches namely `develop` and `master` locally and in github(remotely). But with a major difference.

### Local

```
 master  : identical to last working and stable develop branch
 develop : development branch
```

### Remote

```
 master  : used the following command for this `git subtree push --prefix dist origin master`

 develop : development branch
```

Now my colleague cloned the master branch in his machine and updated a single file, the pushed to **remote master** branch.

Then I thought, oh okay, that is fine, I can just do:

```
git subtree pull --prefix dist origin master
```

Since it is just the opposite of the previous `push` command, but it gave me a **conflict** on the updated file, then I thought, okay I'll just fix and merge the conflict then `subtree push` again, but it gave me:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:user/xxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What could be the problem? Is there a **right** way to do this.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a repository available to the public?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already made some commits, you can do the following

git pull --rebase

This will place all your local commits on top of newly pulled changes.